# clicklistener: how to get my mouselistener record every click on a given button

Tags: javascript, button, mouseclick-event

I'm currently recording all the mouse clicks on my html file. I have two functions for that. The first one is a general listener and records all the mouse clicks. The second one is for clicks on the html elements like buttons. The code for these two mouse events is below. When  I click on a button the second function records this event. However when I click a second time on the same button right afterwards, the first function records it. In that case, I can't see on the log, that the click was on a button. How can I modify my code, so that even several consequent clicks on the button will be recorded by the respective function?

```
//general mouse click listener
document.addEventListener('click', showClickCoords, true);
function showMovementCoords(event) {
        trackedData.push("Date.now()    +" "+
        event.clientX.toString()+"_"+event.clientY.toString());
}

//listener for html elements
document.getElementById("clickOnMe").addEventListener("focus", function(event) {focusFunction(event);});

function focusFunction(event) {
    trackedData.push(Date.now()+" " +event.target.id );
}
```

Comment: I assume your actual code does not have a syntax error

Comment: no it doesn't. sorry for the typo.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying..... If you click on a button it gets focused. If it is focused, it is not going to fire the focus event because it if focused alredy.

Comment: @epascarello, newbie here, still learning. Thx! I got a simple work around below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `focus` listener. That means that whenever you focus the button it will trigger that listener, so if you have already clicked it once, you will have to focus something else and then focus that button again. To fix the behavior you should just use a `click` listener instead.

```js
var trackedData = [];

document.addEventListener('click', showMovementCoords, true);

function showMovementCoords(event) {
  trackedData.push("Date.now()    +" + event.clientX.toString() + "_" + event.clientY.toString());
  console.log(trackedData);
}

document.getElementById("clickOnMe").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  focusFunction(event);
  console.log(trackedData);
});

function focusFunction(event) {
  trackedData.push(Date.now() + " " + event.target.id);
}
```

```html
<button id="clickOnMe">Click on me</button>
```

Comment: THANKS! thats way more simple than I thought. I wasn't aware the focus function doesn't work like that..

Comment: @artre If that answered your question, you can upvote and/or accept this answer